# Some questions in measure theory.

Tags: measure-theory

I got two questions.

Suppose we have the statement

> If a property Q holds a.e, then P holds a.e.

Wouldd the contrapositive be,

> If ~P a.e, then ~Q a.e.

Or would we remove a.e and say it holds everywhere?

Also can someone check if this argument is valid (I've seen the proof elsewhere, but this is the one I wrote).

> If $f,g$ are continuous functions on $[a,b]$ with $f = g$ a.e, then in fact $f = g$.

I basically said let $x \in \{ x : f \neq g \}$ and WLOG, let $f - g > 0$.

Setting $h = f - g$, and for small $\delta$, we get $h(x + \delta) - h(x) > 0$. Passing the limit gives $0 > 0$ (by continuity), a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

You should insert quantifiers: "$P$ holds a.e." can be written as

$$(\exists N \in \mathcal{A}) \: \mu(N)=0 \wedge \left [ (\forall x \in X \setminus N) \: P(x) \right ].$$

So the negation of that can be written as

$$(\forall N \in \mathcal{A}) \: \mu(N) \neq 0 \vee \left [ (\exists x \in X \setminus N) \: \neg P(x) \right ].$$

A slightly nicer form:

$$(\forall N \in \mathcal{A}) \: \mu(N) = 0 \Rightarrow \left [ (\exists x \in X \setminus N) \: \neg P(x) \right ].$$

The intuitive meaning is "the property fails on a set of positive measure".

Comment: Ah so it is just *everywhere*.

Comment: @Hawk Nope, be careful! $N$ in this context is a measurable set.

Comment: uh but doesn't $\mu(N) \neq 0 \nRightarrow \mu(X - N) = 0$?

Comment: @Hawk Basically, the negation says that the property fails on a set of positive measure. I also see now that I made an error, which I am correcting now.

Comment: but isn't that the same as $\sim P$ a.e, here $\sim P$ denotes the failure a.e., so $\sim P$ doesn't hold on a set of measure zero and $\sim P$ holds on some set of $\mu > 0.$ (edit, latex didn't display $\sim$)

Comment: @Hawk No. For instance, consider the statement "$x>0$ a.e." This statement is false. But the statement "$x \leq 0$ a.e." is also false. The true statement is "$x \leq 0$ on a set of positive measure".

Comment: when you say on *a* set of positive measure, do we know the underlying set? In your example, wouldn't it be $m\{ x \leq 0 \} > 0$?

Comment: These are basically the same, except that $\{ x : P (x) \} $ might not necessarily be measurable.

Comment: But if it is measurable, then what I said about $m(x\leq 0)$ is correct? I mean if it isn't measurable, then isn't this discussion not meaningful…? Is my argument for my second question correct?

Comment: If it is measurable then what you said is correct. But in principle it could be a non measurable set with a measurable subset with positive measure.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't thing you can say that WLOG, let $f - g > 0$.  I don't see any reason why they both couldn't oscillate and switch relative positions very often.  However even if $f - g > 0$ you still have a problem with $h(x + \delta) - h(x) > 0$.  In your case $h(x + \delta) > 0$ and $h(x) > 0$, but I don't see why the difference would have to be positive.

Comment: And even if $h(x+ \delta) - h(x) >0$ for all small $\delta >0$, we do not get a contradiction when we pass the limit, as the limit-function does not preserve $>$, it merely preserves $\ge $.